# Partial Replica Synchronization for MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, replication

I need a means to create a SQL Server Express partial replica of a SQL Server 2014 server database and then synchronize the two, triggered by a C# command.  Eventually, there could be as many as a hundred partial replicas on various clients.  Anyone know how I can do this and where I should look to learn how to do it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SymmetricDS is a product that will synchronize SQL Server 2014 with SQL Server Express either in a partial sync scenario or full sync scenario.   You configure which tables you need to synchronize.  It will by default synch in near real time based on your configuration or you can schedule a variety of jobs to meet your needs.   To support your C# use case you could look into the JMX and/or REST API's provided as well.

[SymmetricDS Open Source](http://www.symmetricds.org/)

[SymmetricDS Professional](http://www.jumpmind.com/products/symmetricds/overview)